# How to open several jmx files in jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I write new test plan.

I have existing plan where I want to copy severl steps.

When I try to open new test plan - old closes and vice versa.

Is threre way to achieve my aim ?

Comment: Run multiple Jmeter instance ?

Answer (score 2):

You can merge plans: open one plan, to which you want to copy, select **File > Merge** and select another plan, from which you want to copy. Then rearrange both plans the way you want. Before doing so, you can also save "second plan to only contain parts you want, so that you don't need too much cleaning